# AttributeError: 'QgsVectorLayer' object has no attribute 'geometry'. How to fix?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, geometry

Ok... So I am trying to add a column (Length) in attribut table that shows the length of each line of a line feature. A part of my code is this:

```
            geom = layer.geometry()
            len = geom.length()
            processing.runalg('qgis:fieldcalculator', layer_output2, 'Length', 0, 10, 2, True, len, layer_output2)
```

And the error says that QgsVectorLayer has no attribute 'geometry'...What am I missing?

QgsVectorLayer is here:

```
    for layer in layers:
        if layer.type() == QgsMapLayer.VectorLayer:
            self.dlg.layerCombo.addItem( layer.name(), layer )
```

Maybe my data has a problem...but everything else I try to do, worked. 
So, maybe my code is wrong...(probably, I am not good at coding).
Any tips?

Comment: https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#add-geometry-attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The QgsVectorLayer class does not have the function geometry. https://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html. Maybe you should use:

```
for feature in layer.getFeatures():
    print(feature.geometry().length())
```

Answer (score 2):

Let’s point out some useful information:
1 - A layer has features.
2 - A feature has a geometry

With that in mind, you need to iterate over the features in your layer. For each feature you do:

```
for feature in layer.getFeatures():
    geom = feature.geometry()
    len = geom.length()
```

And so on...